# Set Kendo dialog window width at run-time (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, modal-dialog, kendo-ui-angular2

How do you customize the width of a Kendo dialog window using a variable? For example, at any given time I may want it to be either be 350px, 500px, or 750px.

I have tried:

```
<kendo-dialog style="{{width}}"></kendo-dialog>
...
width = "width=500px";
```

This sets the entire area to 500px, not the window.

The following doesn't seem to do anything

```
<kendo-dialog width="{{width}}"></kendo-dialog>
...
width = "500";
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following issue:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/113